# Cambiar velocidad en Amazon Polly con Python

Tags: python, aws

estoy usando Amazon Polly desde Python y hasta ahora toda va perfecto estoy usando la voz neuronal, llamada "Lupe", pero necesito manejar la velocidad, según la documentación de Amazon es posible cambiar la velocidad pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo de cómo usarlo en Python. Si alguien conoce cómo hacerlo les agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71186084/236345), sería algo así:

```
import boto3

polly_client = boto3.Session(
               aws_access_key_id='your_access_key_id',
               aws_secret_access_key='your_secret_access_key',
               region_name='your_region').client('polly')


response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(
               VoiceId='Joanna',
               OutputFormat='mp3',
               Engine = 'neural', 
               TextType = "ssml", 
               Text = "<speak><prosody rate='90%'>The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog</prosody></speak>") # prosody rate changes the speed of the speech.

with open('folder/speech.mp3', 'wb') as file: #the folder part is here if you want to create the mp3 in a specific folder, if you don't want that, just remove it.
   file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())
```

Usando una etiqueta SSML para indicarle en qué parte *ne ce si tas* que vaya a otra velocidad. Eso es lo que dice [la documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voice-speed-vip.html). De hecho, el código de ejemplo [tiene](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/SynthesizeSpeechSamplePython.html) un enlace para *controlar mejor el output del sintetizador* que [lleva](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/ssml.html) a la documentación del soporte para etiquetas SSML.

Mira las [etiquetas soportadas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/supportedtags.html) para que veas qué hay disponible. Entendería que no todas están en todos los idiomas...